# difference between invoke and init kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, operator-overloading, invoke, init

I'm studying about operator overloading in kotlin and I ran into `invoke` method. When I did my research about it I found out it works much similar to `init` constructor of every class.
I cannot get my head around the difference and they seem to be alike because everything we do in `invoke` method, it can be done in `init` constructor as well.

so what is the difference and when should we use each?

Comment: I don't understand your point "everything we do in invoke method, it can be done in init constructor". `invoke` is a method (which happens to be also an operator), and `init` is an initializing block - they have nothing in common. I assume your problem is the lack of investing into reading the docs and trying out the code

Comment: @Neo I don't know what you got from my question, but I wasn't asking about the structure. I asked what is the usage of each.

Comment: invoke can be used on lambdas especially on nullable lambdas to call the body with the required arguments while init is a block that is called after constructor call of a  class to create an object to initialize some property or to do other stuff. No idea why you are confused about them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is not a good comparison. The `init` block is run every time the class is instantiated, with any kind of constructor as we shall see next. But the `invoke` method can be called multiple times, just like any other method of the class.
Suppose you want to return all the values of a class as string in different parts of the code. You can implement it in invoke and call it wherever necessary without naming the function.

example:

```
class Person(val name :String,var age:Int) {
    
    fun incrementAge(){
        age =age + 1   
    }

    operator fun invoke():String {
        
        return "name: $name \nage:  $age\n"
    }
}

fun main() {
    
    val x = Person("lionel",35)
    println(x())
    x.incrementAge()
    println(x())
}
```

Output:

```
name: lionel 
age:  35

name: lionel 
age:  36
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. tbh it wasn't only me, I saw multiple student asking my question without getting any answers. I was confused because I thought the result will appear whenever it is instantiated but now I got it completely. thank you so much.